# How to add new functions to ng-blur in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I want to add a new function to the ng-blur of all input/textarea fields.
The input fields and textarea's has a existing ng-blur in the html and I want to add a new function to the existing ng-blur within the controller.

I tried to add it with setAttribute, but that override the existing ng-blur functions.

```
const formElems= iElem[0].querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
formElems[0].setAttribute('data-ng-blur', 'newFunction()');
$compile(angular.element(formElems[0]))($scope);
```

I want to extend the functions inside ng-blur, but not directly in the HTML.

How to add new functions inside the controller to the ng-blur of all input and textarea's and keep the current functions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in your template.

Just create a new function in your controller and call this function from already exists function. It will not break your existing functionality.

See example below -

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName= "John";
  $scope.lastName= "Doe";
  
  $scope.myFunction = function(){
    console.log('Your current working code');
    $scope.extendedFunction();
  }
  
  $scope.extendedFunction = function(){
    console.log('You should write your new code here');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-blur="myFunction();"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" ng-blur="myFunction();"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking for the same, but some input fields doesn't have a function or is not the same function. 

Is there not an alternative which extends in the controller and not in a exists function?

Comment: I am not getting an alternative to this. But you can do one thing, for those inputs which currently not have any event on blur, you can add `extendedDunction` as an event. And for those which have another function, at the last in the function, you can call `extendedDunction` as we are calling from `myFunction`.

Comment: ok thanks @Alok Mali for your comment. I will search for a solution, maybe someone have the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution by getting the existing attribute first by using getAttribute().

```
const oldAttributes = formElems[0].getAttribute('ng-blur');
formElems[0].setAttribute('ng-blur', oldAttributes + ' testConsole();');
```